# Outputting more than one User Ban Data using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to display the current users bans. They do display, but it only outputs 1 detail, when I'm trying to `fetchAll` data for that current user.

Here is my code

```
function getPlayerBans($username, $conn) {
        $getPlayerBans = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, player, bannedby, comment, expires, time FROM `bans` WHERE player = :Player");
        $getPlayerBans->bindValue(":Player", $username);
        $getPlayerBans->execute();
        $rows = $getPlayerBans->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $id1 = $row['bannedby'];
            $id2 = $row['comment'];
            $id3 = $row['expires'];

        }
        if($getPlayerBans->rowCount() == 0) 
        {
            echo('No Results Available');
        }else{
        echo "<table id=\"gradient-style\" summary=\"Meeting Results\">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope=\"col\"><b>Banned By</b></th>
        <th scope=\"col\"><b>Comments</b></th>
        <th scope=\"col\"><b>Expires</b></th>
        <th scope=\"col\"><b>Actions</b></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th>$id1</th>
        <th>$id2</th>
        <th>$id3</th>
        <th><img width=\"32px\" height=\"32px\" title=\"Delete\" src=\"/../cp_mod/images/trash_can.png\"></th>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>";

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the `foreach` loop around the code that prints each row of the table.

```
$rows = $getPlayerBans->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (count($rows) == 0) {
    echo('No Results Available');
} else {
    echo "<table id=\"gradient-style\" summary=\"Meeting Results\">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope=\"col\"><b>Banned By</b></th>
        <th scope=\"col\"><b>Comments</b></th>
        <th scope=\"col\"><b>Expires</b></th>
        <th scope=\"col\"><b>Actions</b></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>";
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $id1 = $row['bannedby'];
        $id2 = $row['comment'];
        $id3 = $row['expires'];
        echo "<tr>
                <th>$id1</th>
                <th>$id2</th>
                <th>$id3</th>
                <th><img width=\"32px\" height=\"32px\" title=\"Delete\" src=\"/../cp_mod/images/trash_can.png\"></th>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>
        </table>";
}
```